# OAuth Auto Refresh Token if token is expired

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, inner-classes, final, local-variables

I'm going to make a login system with **OAuth2.0** for my app, Everything is right until reach to **Expired Token**!

For this section i wrote this method:

```
public static String getAccessToken(){

    String accessToken;

    if(!UserSession.getInstance().isExpired()){
        return UserSession.getInstance().getUserAuthAccessToken();
    } else {

        PostRequests.getFreshToken(new ResultListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void getResult(String result, boolean error) {

                if(error){

                } else {

                    Authorization authorization = gson.fromJson(result, Authorization.class);
                    UserSession.getInstance().setUserAuthorizationInfo(authorization.AccessToken, authorization.TokenType, authorization.Expiration, authorization.RefreshToken, authorization.Scope);
                    accessToken = authorization.AccessToken;
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

As you can see, I return access token store in my app shared prefrences if is not expired, but if was expired, I make Refresh Request ( Volley + Gson), to make that fresh.

But I can't reach `accessToken` from inner class :(

How I can return String from this method?

Answer (score 2):

Using listener is one way to resolve this issue.

```
public interface ITokenListener {
    void onTokenObtained(String accessToken);
}

public void usingGetAccessTokenMethod() {
    getAccessToken(new ITokenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTokenObtained(String accessToken) {
            //use accessToken
        }
    });
}

public void getAccessToken(final ITokenListener listener){

    if(!UserSession.getInstance().isExpired()){
        listener.onTokenObtained(UserSession.getInstance().getUserAuthAccessToken());
    } else {

        PostRequests.getFreshToken(new ResultListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void getResult(String result, boolean error) {

                if(error){

                } else {

                    Authorization authorization = gson.fromJson(result, Authorization.class);
                    UserSession.getInstance().setUserAuthorizationInfo(authorization.AccessToken, authorization.TokenType, authorization.Expiration, authorization.RefreshToken, authorization.Scope);
                    listener.onTokenObtained(UserSession.getInstance().getUserAuthAccessToken());
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Its does not help, because I'm going to use `.getAccessToken()` to append token to end of my request url like `final String URL = Constant.BaseUrl + Constant.Token + getAccessToken()`

Comment: you can do something like this 
public void usingGetAccessTokenMethod() {
    getAccessToken(new ITokenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTokenObtained(String accessToken) {
            final String URL = Constant.BaseUrl + Constant.Token + accessToken + Constant.Limit;
   //use the url here
        }
    });
}

but as I said this is one of the way.